# I have a problem with my native query using spring data jpa

Tags: database, spring, oracle, jpa

I have a query that i can get result from oracle db, but when i use that query as native query in spring data jpa. I am getting exception as invalid table name

Here is my running query

```
SELECT listagg(COLUMN_TWO,' ') within group (order by COLUMN_TWO) 
FROM (select 'RDIFP' as val from dual union all
      select 'RDIFP' as val from dual union all
      select 'DROWM' as val from dual
     ) v left join
     TABLE_NAME_ONE 
     on v.val = COLUMN_TWO, TABLE_NAME_TWO, TABLE_NAME_THREE
WHERE 
COLUMN_THREE = COLUMN_FOUR AND  
COLUMN_FIVE = COLUMN_SIX AND 
COLUMN_ONE = '176134'
```

I am using it in spring data jpa code below

```
static final String QUERY_VALUES =
            "SELECT listagg(COLUMN_TWO,' ') within group (order by COLUMN_TWO) 
FROM (:prQry) v left join
     TABLE_NAME_ONE 
     on v.val = COLUMN_TWO, TABLE_NAME_TWO, TABLE_NAME_THREE
WHERE 
COLUMN_THREE = COLUMN_FOUR AND  
COLUMN_FIVE = COLUMN_SIX AND 
COLUMN_ONE = '176134'";

@Query(value = QUERY_VALUES, nativeQuery=true)
String getValuesById(@Param("prQry") String prQry);
```

For the parameter `prQry` i will generate query dynamically and have it in string and pass it as parameter since i will pass the value as

```
String prQry= "select 'RDIFP' as val from dual union all
      select 'RDIFP' as val from dual union all
      select 'DROWM' as val from dual";
```

after iteration dynamically i will be getting like above.

After implementing when i run it, i am getting the exception as invalid table name. Can anyone help me on this issue to use it in different way or have i done anything wrong in my code.

Comment: what is that `v.val = COLUMN_TWO, TABLE_NAME_TWO, TABLE_NAME_THREE` can you explain what are you trying to do here? did you try to execute your query in your IDE for database ?

Comment: in my ide it doesn't work, in running query in sqldeveloper it works fine

Comment: for 'v.val = COLUMN_TWO, TABLE_NAME_TWO, TABLE_NAME_THREE' i am using multiple tables and column_two is from table_name_one. I could not write the original query so for naming i have changed the table and column names for understanding

Comment: Hi @ManojKumar, I added an answer here, see if this helps you to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @ManojKumar, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve this with Spring Data Repositories, because the parms would translate as a String and in the FINAL query you you have:

```
SELECT listagg(COLUMN_TWO,' ') within group (order by COLUMN_TWO)
FROM ("select 'RDIFP' as val from dual ... ") v
```

This would show as string and invalid query. The @Param it is only for WHERE clause.

One way of achieving what you want is using the EntityManager:

```
@Autowired 
EntityManager entityManager;

static final String QUERY_VALUES =
        "SELECT listagg(COLUMN_TWO,' ') within group (order by COLUMN_TWO) 
            FROM (:prQry) v left join
                 TABLE_NAME_ONE 
                 on v.val = COLUMN_TWO, TABLE_NAME_TWO, TABLE_NAME_THREE
            WHERE 
            COLUMN_THREE = COLUMN_FOUR AND  
            COLUMN_FIVE = COLUMN_SIX AND 
            COLUMN_ONE = '176134'";

public String getValuesById(String prQry) {
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QUERY_VALUES.replace(":prQry", prQry), String.class);
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
```

This is the idea anyway for dynamic queries when you change the FROM condition.